# ASP.NET in VS IDE gives "Expression cannot be evaluated at this time."

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I read all of similar questions in SO but none seem to be an answer.

Situation is simple. I have a ASP.NET webpage,

In a VB code behind file I have the following line:

```
 iRendProvider = ddlProvider.SelectedItem.Value
```

where iRendProvider  is integer and ddlProvider is a dropdownlist.

I put a breakpoint at the above line and code stops there.

Now in the immdediate window in I type:

? ddlProvider.SelectedItem.Value

I get "Expression cannot be evaluated at this time."

If I step over

```
iRendProvider = ddlProvider.SelectedItem.Value
```

To the next line and I type ? iRendProvider  , I see the correct value in the immediate window.

Question is why this error and how to see contents of ddlProvider.

Comment: How do you populate ddlProvider?

Comment: did you try .SelectedValue

Comment: Did you see if the AutoPostBack is set to True? With a drop down until the server posts back its not technically selected.

Comment: SelectedValue  produces same message.

Comment: @Alexander: Good question.ddlProvider gets its values from a dropdownlist inside a cell of datagrid which is bound to a database column. (grdService is a data grid) `ddlProvider = grdService.Items(grdService.EditItemIndex).Cells(3).Controls(1)`. I have a feeling when this is the case IDE has trouble showing the values.

Comment: In immdediate windows Even the following line gives Error:

' ? ddlProvider.Width
error: cannot obtain value '

Comment: So you're using ddlProvider as a reference, or is it a drop down list on its own?

Comment: ddlProvider is a dropdownlist as mentioned above:
'ddlProvider = grdService.Items(grdService.EditItemIndex).Cells(3).Controls(1)'

I did not add this drop downlist the the form using the toolbox. The sole purpose of this DDL is to get values of the embeded dropdownlist in Datagrid cell.